# (HERE API) PositioningManager Does Not (sometimes) get the position, while Position Indicator Is In The Correct Position

Tags: android, mvvm, here-api

I want to set the center of the map to my current location and make position indicator visible.

However sometimes the position returns -1.7976931348623157E308lat -1.7976931348623157E308 lng. Sometimes this doesn't fix itself and sometimes it never happens at all.

Weird part is if I pan to the location of the device I can see the location indicator at the correct position.

I'm trying to implement MVVM for this project (to the best of my knowledge) so I have a currentLocation in my repository and I apply viewmodel.getCurrentLocation().observe in my View.

I have not faced this issue before even though I have worked with HERE Maps in the past. Any insight would be appreciated, I can provide more details if requested.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting an updated position of user with the use of positing listener like

```
private val positionListener = object : NavigationManager.PositionListener() {
    override fun onPositionUpdated(geoPosition: GeoPosition?) {
        map.setCenter(geoPosition?.coordinate, Map.Animation.LINEAR)
    }
}
```

try with this. It is working fine for me